# width of dynamically inserted div containing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a script that dynamically inserts a div containing text in the dom. The text content is not known in advance.

I need to know the width of this div, but it seems that that the return value of `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(node, "").getPropertyValue("width")` or node.offsetWidth cannot be trusted.

I used setInterval to log it, and the value changes over time. For instance, in my case it starts with 929px and then changes to 908px.

This div is in position absolute, it has whitespace nowrap, so I don't think it is being "pushed" by other dom elements or that it somehow changes once inserted.

Is there an elegant way to retrieve the width, or do I have to use an ugly setTimeout to retrieve it once the return value is stable ?

Comment: You should add an example, it's hard to believe the value changes over time unless you animate it or change the contents in a timeout. Questions without code are not as useful

Comment: if you could show an example of what your specific problem is, i could give you a solution maybe use jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net, but once a node is attached to the DOM you should be able to get it's width and it should be stable, especially if it is absolute positioned

Comment: The `div` size could change if it contains an image which size is not known in advance.

Comment: @JanDvorak That's so true, it could cause similar problems. However, in this case, the width is getting smaller, so I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: I believe the issue is the document scrollbar. See my answer.

Comment: "once a node is attached to the DOM" I think ckoz may have hinted the right answer. I need to check when I get back at work. my code builds a larger html object that contains divs with text. I think the whole object may not be inserted at the moment where i check its size. I do that with jQuery. maybe jQuery uses documentFragment internally to dom manipulation. Ok, I'm just guessing, I need to see the code, I ll tell in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
yourDOMElement.getClientBoundingRect()
```

This will return an object with top, left, right, bottom, height and **width** attributes. This should be cross-browser.

Note: If you are going to work with the position attributes (top, left, right, bottom, height) of the returned, take into account scroll offset if necessary.

**Update:** To ensure this works on older browsers that don't have the width/height attribute, calculate it subtracting right/bottom from left/top.

Comment: width and height, are *newish* additions, so you are better off taking right - left if you want it to be cross browser

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Do you know off the top of your head which older browsers don't have __width__ and __height__ attributes? Would be good to know for the future.

Comment: IE < 9 for one, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536433(v=vs.85).aspx  AND  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535906(v=vs.85).aspx  "When webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, the TextRange object also supports properties that return the height and the width of the object."

Comment: Thanks ckoz, good to know. I've updated the answer with your input.

Answer (score 1):

The viewport can change its size because of the scrollbar. Once the scrollbar appears, its width can no longer be used by the document. Force the scrollbar to exist before you measure the size by adding `overflow: scroll` or `overflow-y:scroll` to the `<html>` element.

The size of a block-level element is, by default, its container width minus margins and padding (even if it's `position`ed `absolute`ly), which is ultimately the wiewport width unless you set a fixed width somewhere along the way.

Comment: Since the OP doesn't show teh codez, I think this is the most plausible answer. However, the scrollbars are usually 17-19px wide, in this case the difference is 21px... Maybe the OP has a theme with really thick scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you should be able to do this:

```
var width = $("div-selector").width();
```

Answer (score -2):

this is fairly easy?

open the page in a browser and press f12. With firefox there is a button "inspect element" on top and in chrome it's on the bottom. Click it and hover your mouse over it. This should give you the height and width in px. Never been wrong for me.

if it still doesn't show, click it and you can see it in the css panel of the console.

Comment: i think he is trying to get the width programmatically